# Why my exports are limited to 100 records only in django-import-export?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-import-export

I am using Django import export in my project.

I have ~5000 records in the model.

In local, The export is working fine. [exporting all the records in csv]
But in production, when I export to csv, Only 100 records are exported.

The django app is hosted on Cpanel.
I am using mysql phpmyadmin in production.

Is there any limit in the cpanel to export in django import-export module which I can change because the problem I am facing in production only.

**database config in settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': '********',
        'USER': '*********',
        'PASSWORD': '*********',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'sql_mode': 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES',
        },
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
class Treatment(models.Model):
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='alltreatments', null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null= True, blank= True)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='treatmentlanguage', blank= True, null=True)
    searched_treatment = models.CharField(max_length= 256, blank= False, null= False)
    price = models.FloatField(blank= False, null= False)
    price_type = models.CharField(max_length= 256, blank= True, null= True)
    package_info_1 = models.CharField(max_length= 556, blank= True, null= True)
    package_info_2 = models.CharField(max_length= 556, blank= True, null= True)
    package_info_3 = models.CharField(max_length= 556, blank= True, null= True)
    package_info_4 = models.CharField(max_length= 556, blank= True, null= True)
    currency=models.ForeignKey(Currency,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='currency',blank=True,null=True)
    created= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default= True)

    class Meta:
        # unique_together = ('clinic', 'searched_treatment', 'language')
        ordering=('-created',)
        verbose_name_plural='Treatments'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.searched_treatment

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = self.searched_treatment
        self.slug = slugify(slug)
        super(Treatment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Model Resource**

```
class TreatmentResource(resources.ModelResource):
    currency = fields.Field(column_name='currency',attribute='currency', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Currency, 'name'))
    language = fields.Field(column_name='language',attribute='language', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Language, 'code'))
    clinic = fields.Field(column_name='clinic',attribute='clinic', widget=TreatmentForeignKeyWidget(Clinic, 'code'))

    class Meta:
        model = Treatment
        fields = ('searched_treatment', 'price_type', 'price', 'package_info_1', 'package_info_2', 'package_info_3', 'package_info_4')
        exclude = ('id',)
        import_id_fields = ('searched_treatment', 'price_type', 'price', 'package_info_1', 'package_info_2', 'package_info_3', 'package_info_4', 'currency', 'language', 'clinic')
```

**Model Admin**

```
class TreatmentAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin, ExportCsvMixin):
    resource_class = TreatmentResource
    search_fields = ['searched_treatment' ]
    actions = ["export_as_csv"]
    field_names = ["slug"]


    def get_import_formats(self):
        formats = (
                base_formats.CSV,
        )
        return [f for f in formats if f().can_export()]
```

***THANKS IN ADVANCE***

Comment: 100 is the default [chunk size](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#import-export-chunk-size) in which it will fetch and process data from your database. It's likely that an error is occuring with the second chunk of data, which is why it never gets written to file - you should get some clues in the admin logs (assuming you haven't disabled these) or if you enable [transactions](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#import-export-use-transactions) so that the whole thing fails if there is an error.

Comment: @solarissmoke is there a way I can change the chunk size? And also where I can find admin logs?

Comment: I linked in my first comment to the documentation which shows you how to change the chunk size. The documentation will also tell you where to find the admin logs.

Comment: @solarissmoke Thanks a lot bro! I increase the CHUNK SIZE and it worked :D !

Answer (score 0):

if not chunk, you can check if its limited to 1000 as the number of fields are   restricted by `DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS` or it can be due to max number of files or size - `DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FILES`, `DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE`

ref:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/